# Why is there a space after the first letter?

Tags: c, file, printf, space

I have this code:

```
void text(){    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( "Text.txt", "w" );
    if (fp == NULL)printf("not open\n");
    char txt[100];
    char c;
while(1){   
    char c = getche();
    if (c == '\e')
        break;
    txt[0] = c;
    gets(txt+1);
    fprintf(fp, "%s ",txt);
}
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It works fine and the output would be like: `Hello there.`

```
void text(){    
    char fname[20] ; 
    puts("Write file name");
    scanf("%s",&fname); //input of the file name
    char ext[5] = ".txt";
    char fileSpec[strlen(fname)+strlen(ext)+1]; //file name assambly
    snprintf( fileSpec, sizeof( fileSpec ), "%s%s", fname, ext);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( fileSpec, "w" );
    if (fp == NULL)printf("not open\n");
    char txt[100];
    char c;
while(1){   
    char c = getche();
    if (c == '\e')
        break;
    txt[0] = c;
    gets(txt+1);
    fprintf(fp, "%s ",txt);
}
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I took the top half from a website, tested it separately and it worked. The bottom half is the same and when i put the two together the output would be like this: `H ello there.`

Why is that space there?

Comment: Not possible to answer.   `getche()` is not a standard C function, and `'\e'` is not a valid escape code.   You are using non-standard (vendor specific) features, and the interactions between them depend on too many things related to how your vendor does things.

Comment: Never use `gets()`. It is inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language. `fgets()` can be used safely, though it requires a little more effort (it leaves the trailing `'\n'`, if any, in the target array).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough context (i.e. What was put into stdin? What was in the file?).

But your `fprintf(fp, "%s ",txt);` has a space in it, and that seems like the likely culprit. (Note that the while loop can run more than one time, thus adding spaces between what it outputs to the file).

Comment: The input was `text` for the name and the file is empty

Comment: large part of the question was edited by someone so most context isn't there anymore. I am using Dev-C++ , and i tried removing the space before `"%s"` and using `fgets`, but it didn't help.

Comment: With the reasonable assumption that `getche` is kind of standard thing and `gets` does not misbehave, the observed result could come from: 1. Typing 'H', 2. Typing "enter" so `gets` terminates immediately (!), 3. Typing "ello world", followed by another enter.

Comment: I typed `hello` as a whole and i got `h ello` back, then i tried to  hitting enter at the start and i got a whole `hello` out in the next loop, it seems that the first loop accepts and prints only one character.